# Where is the default 'Login' view and corresponding controller in the template MVC Core application in VS2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, visual-studio-2019

Odd one this, I must be missing something obvious but with a brand new MVC web application, with Authentication, it builds the DB migrations for the asp user tables and puts the _LoginPartial in _Layout etc. and login works fine, I can login and register etc but I can't find the view or code to alter it.

I navigate to localhost:blah/Identity/Account/Login and can login, but there's no view in the project that corresponds, there's an /Areas/Identity folder but it only has /Pages under it, no /Account and there's no Login.cshtml or anything called Account anywhere in the project.

Very odd, I keep thinking I'm just being dim and will look again tomorrow but have done that a few times. I've tried searching for it but only find false matches.

I've created a brand new application from the template a few times now thinking I somehow messed up the choices in the dialogues but it seems so basic - the view is obviously somewhere as it loads up and works fine, but where's MVC getting it view from, and where is the controller it's calling ??

Similarly, I search the project for some text on the page, eg. 'Use a local account to log in', both in VS and using grep on the entire source folder but it's not anywhere.

Comment: Take a quick look at the docs and you see that those views are now in a separate library by default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#identity-components

Comment: Thanks very much, I got a bit focused on searching for 'login', I should have tried 'identity', that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

To fill out the answer to the question behind my question - i.e. how can I customise the login page. To generate the views and code in-project, right click on the Areas/Identity folder in the project, select 'Add' and 'New Scaffolded item...', select Identity and go from there.

Trying that generated an error for me, with a Core 2.2 project; but I retried in a virgin Core 2.1 solution and it worked OK, I then transferred the added folders and files to my 2.2 solution, changed the namespaces to match and I can now alter the login form and log in with it OK.

The account management function to change the phone number also works, so seems like it's all hooked up OK, I've not tried any of the other identify functionality as yet.

Thanks again to Nkosi for the answer.